# Can't see app is opened in Firebase Analytics dashboard

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I set up Firebase in my Unity game. Then imported Authentication, Analytics, and Database. Authentication and Database code, initialization is working well but I can't see any action in Analytics.

Here is what I did,

1- I imported Analytics correctly (I think).

2- I attached AnalyticsManager.cs to empty GameObject and located GameObject in scene.

3- and write the initialization codes and I think it's also okey. here is the code;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Firebase.Extensions;

public class AnalyticsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Firebase.FirebaseApp app;
    void Start()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
                FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.EventAppOpen);
                FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.EventLogin);
                print("analytics initialized");
                app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                if(app != null)
                {
                    print("analytics app started.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogErrorFormat("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus);
            }
        });
        
    }

    void Update()
    { }
}
```

What the problem could be?